# App crashes while applying loading footer while displaying listvview using on scroll listener

Tags: android, listview, footer, onscroll

My listview initially loads 15 items . When the user scrolls to the end the list view should load next 15 items and so on and this process continues. While the list view loads it should display loading footer. But when I run the app the first 15 items load and when scrolled to last to load next items the app crashes.

My code

```
public class InterActivity extends Activity 
{

 ListView listview;
 List<ParseObject> ob;
 ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 FinalAdapter adapter;
 List<CodeList> codelist = null;
 SharedPreference shrdPreference;
 private int limit = 15;
 View footerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.inter_layout);
  shrdPreference = new SharedPreference();
  //Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
  new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Create a progresssdialog
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
    // Set progressdialog title
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    // Set progressdialog messsage
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading ...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Create the array
    codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
    try {
      // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("InterActivity");
      // Locate the columnn named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
      // by ascending
      query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
      query.setLimit(limit);
      ob = query.find();

      for (ParseObject inter : ob) {
        map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
        map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));
        codelist.add(map);
      }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
    adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this, codelist);

    // AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
    // animationAdapter.setAbsListView(listview);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ListVieww
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    //listview.setOnItemClickListener(InterActivity.this);

    //listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(InterActivity.this); 
    // Close the progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    //setup onscrll listener
    listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                         int scrollState) { // TODO Auto generated method stubb
          int threshold = 1;
          int count = listview.getCount();

          if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
              - threshold) {
              // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
              new Loadmore().execute();
            }
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                   int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
  }
}

private class Loadmore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null, false); 
    listview.addFooterView(footerView);
    super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Create the array
    codelist.clear();

    try {
      // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
        "InterActivity");
      // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
      // by ascending
      query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
      query.setLimit(limit += 15);
      ob = query.find();
      for (ParseObject inter : ob) {          
        map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));
        codelist.add(map);
      }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listview.removeFooterView(footerView);

    listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);

    super.onPostExecute(result);
  }
}
```

**logcat**

> 01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E
>   AndroidRuntime                               Process:
>   com.enlightenme.pac, PID: 12753 01-06 12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E
>   AndroidRuntime
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 1 01-06
>   12:44:53.279 12753 12753 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: What is your min sdk, and what version of Android are you testing with?

Comment: @DanielNugent My minimum sdk version is 17